Simple drawing website using React
So I have recently started learning web dev (including React since a few days ago), and I have tried to implement a simple drawing website that lets you change the brush size, color, and save the picture when you're finished.
I would appreciate any advice regarding style, good practices in React, etc.!
main.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

index.css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

App.jsx
import './App.css'
import DrawingCanvas from './DrawingCanvas'
import ColorButton from './ColorButton'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
    const [color, setColor] = useState('black')
    const [strokeSize, setStrokeSize] = useState(10)
    const [canvasPNGDataURL, setCanvasPNGDataURL] = useState('')
    const colors = ['black', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', '#ff69b4', '#ff8c00', '#00ffff']

   return (
    <div className='outer-container'>
        <div className='top-bar'>
            <input className='stroke-size-input' value={strokeSize} type="text" onChange={(e) => {setStrokeSize(e.target.value)}}/>
            <div className='tool-bar'>
                {colors.map((color) => {
                    return <ColorButton key={color} color={color} colorSetFunction={setColor}></ColorButton>
                })}
            </div>
            <a className="save-button" href={canvasPNGDataURL} download="my-picture">Save</a>
        </div>
        <DrawingCanvas style="flex-grow: 1;" strokeSize={parseInt(strokeSize)} color={color} canvasPNGDataSetter={setCanvasPNGDataURL}></DrawingCanvas>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

App.css
.top-bar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.top-bar > * {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.stroke-size-input {
    height: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:xx-large;
}

.tool-bar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.save-button {
    position: relative;
    height: 40%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    inset: 0;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.outer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ColorButton.jsx
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./ColorButton.css";

export default function ColorButton({ color, colorSetFunction }) {
    function applyColor() {
        colorSetFunction(color);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => {applyColor()}} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}></button>
    );
}

ColorButton.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    colorSetFunction: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

ColorButton.css
button {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border: white solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

DrawingCanvas.jsx
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import './DrawingCanvas.css'

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function DrawingCanvas({ strokeSize, color, canvasPNGDataSetter }) {
  let canvasContext = useRef(null)
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#main-canvas')
    canvasContext.current = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvasContext.current.lineJoin = 'round';
    canvasContext.current.lineCap = 'round';
    canvasContext.current.strokeSize = strokeSize;
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasContext.current.strokeStyle = color;
  }, [color])

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasContext.current.fillStyle = 'white';
    canvasContext.current.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
      const canvas = document.getElementById('main-canvas')
      canvasPNGDataSetter(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    canvasContext.current.lineWidth = strokeSize
  }, [strokeSize])

  function drawIfMousePressed(event) {
    if (event.buttons !== 1) {
      closeDrawPath()
      return
    }
    drawNextLine(event)
  }

  function drawNextLine(event) {
    let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    let x = event.clientX - rect.left
    let y = event.clientY - rect.top

    if (!isDrawing) {
      openDrawPath()
      canvasContext.current.moveTo(x, y)
    } else {
      canvasContext.current.lineTo(x, y)
      canvasContext.current.stroke()
    }
  }

  function closeDrawPath() {
    canvasContext.current.closePath()
    setIsDrawing(false)
  }

  function openDrawPath() {
    canvasContext.current.beginPath()
    setIsDrawing(true)
  }

  return (
    <div className="drawing-canvas-container">
      <canvas className="drawing-canvas" id="main-canvas" height="1000" width="1000" onMouseMove={drawIfMousePressed} onMouseOut={closeDrawPath}></canvas>
    </div>
  )
}

DrawingCanvas.propTypes = {
    strokeSize: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    canvasPNGDataSetter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default DrawingCanvas

DrawingCanvas.css
.drawing-canvas-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    outline: solid green;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}

.drawing-canvas {
    outline: solid black;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
}

